# Mongodb subtraction of two Int32 fields results in null value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing an aggregation of some data, which includes the following projection.

**Query :**

```
{"$project": {
            "subbedout": {"$toInt": {"$ifNull": ["$outmin", "$endgame"]}},
            "subbedin": {"$toInt": {"$ifNull": ["$inmin", 0]}},
            "minutes": {"$subtract": ["$subbedout", "$subbedin"]}
        }
```

The fields subbedout and subbedin are as expected and both **Int32**, but the minutes field values are all **null**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating those two fields in same projection which is causing that issue, you need to split it into two stages or either have to do the operations `{"$toInt": {"$ifNull": ["$outmin", "$endgame"]}}` & `{"$toInt": {"$ifNull": ["$inmin", 0]}}` in `$subtract` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "subbedout": "$a",
      "subbedin": "$b"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "minutes": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$subbedout",
          "$subbedin"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```